# Sending emails for selected rows of data and attaching a Drive File by ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on trying to make a tuition notification system, but am hitting a snag when it comes to attaching the PDFs which are bulk saved in a drive folder.

Sample Spreadsheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kGOVLRBSoBJGnLc3Y_YIDGb42ufVmLJJsjUYSH-E3ts/copy)

One of the sheets has a function to make a list of all the file names / Drive IDs [Tuition PDFs]  -- These are bulk exported from existing software.]

The second sheet matches the Drive File ID with the correct student.

The third sheet allows you to send emails to the target students.

Essentially you mark the check boxes of the students you want to send the files too on a spreadsheet. In one of the columns, vlookup is used to grab all of the file IDs from second sheet. I was able to get the script to send emails based on the selected template chosen to the select students (with no duplicates). However, I can't get the drive files to attach.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
var load = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = load.getActiveSheet();
var template = sheet.getRange("L15").getValue();


function getMessage(notes) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(template);
  var message = htmlOutput.getContent()
  message = message.replace("%notes", notes);
  return message;
}

function sendalert() {

  //Get Email count
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var count = sheet.getRange("M9").getValue();

  //Display confirmation pop-up
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("⚠️ 注意 ⚠️","メールを送りますか"+" ("+count+"件)？", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  
  //Course of action - OK
  if(result === SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1   // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000)
    
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      var row = data[i];
      var checkbox1 =row[8];
      var emailAddress = row[5];
```

I am still a relative beginner at this, but I imagine the problem is somewhere down here.

```
var FileID = row[7];  //// THIS IS WHAT I CAN NOT GET TO WORK YET
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(FileID); //// I WOULD LIKE IT TO TAKE THE PDF FILE LINK IN THE CELL AND SEND IT AS AN ATTACHMENT

      if (emailAddress.match('@') == null){
          continue;
      };  // First column
      
      //Get Additional Comments - convert line breaks to <br>
      var cellWithLineBreaks = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("L2").getValue();
      cellWithLineBreaks = cellWithLineBreaks.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
      var notes = cellWithLineBreaks;

      //Change Email Subject based on selected template
      if (template == "立替金の連絡"){
          var subject = "立替金 引き取り依頼"; 
      }
      
      var message = getMessage(notes);
      var emailSent = row[9];     
      
      if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && checkbox1 == true) {  // Prevents sending duplicates

//--------------------------------------------------------

        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {htmlBody : message, attachments : [file]});  
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
  }

 }
```

**Thanks for taking the time to read all of this!**

Comment: I think that in your script, even when the file of `var file = DriveApp.getFileById(FileID);` is a PDF file and a Google Docs file, the file is attached to the email as the PDF file. So I cannot understand `However, I can't get the drive files to attach.`. In your script, did an error occur? Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: I was able to the attachment the PDF to the email by adding `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {htmlBody : message, attachments : [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});  ` --- However now I get the following error message: `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.`